# Can't get Click or Command to work on dynamically created MenuFlyOutItems

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, event-handling, treeview

I have a TreeView with several layers in it.  Each item is populated with an ObservableCollection of MenuFlyoutItem dependent on its object type created dynamically at runtime. It's important to note this is in a Windows 10 Universal App, so any solutions or recommendations need to be relevant to them.

The TreeView objects are created like so:

```
public TreeViewItemModel(object thing)
    {
        MenuItems.Clear();
        if (thing.GetType() == typeof (Space))
        {
            var space = (Space)thing;
            var parentName = string.Empty;
            if (space.Parent != null)
            {
                parentName = space.Parent.Name;
            }
            Name = space.Name;
            ParentName = parentName;
            Id = space.Id;
            var addDeviceMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "AddDevice", Text = "Add Device"};
            var addSensorMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "AddSensor", Text = "Add Sensor" };
            var addSpaceMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "AddSpace", Text="Add Space"};
            var updateMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "UpdateSpaceInfo", Text = "Update Space Info" };
            var deleteMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "DeleteSpace", Text = "Delete Space" };
            var items = new ObservableCollection<MenuFlyoutItem> {addDeviceMenuItem, addSensorMenuItem,addSpaceMenuItem, updateMenuItem, deleteMenuItem};
            MenuItems = items;
            Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel>(space.Children.Select(s => new TreeViewItemModel(s)).Union(space.Devices.Select(d => new TreeViewItemModel(d)).Union(space.Sensors.Select(sensor => new TreeViewItemModel(sensor)))));
        }

        else if (thing.GetType() == typeof (Device))
        {
            var device = (Device) thing;
            var parentName = device.Space.Name;
            Name = device.Name;
            ParentName = parentName;
            Id = device.Id;
            var addMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "AddSensor", Text = "Add Sensor" };
            var updateMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "UpdateDeviceInfo", Text = "Update Device Info" };
            var deleteMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "DeleteDevice", Text = "Delete Device" };
            var items = new ObservableCollection<MenuFlyoutItem> { addMenuItem, updateMenuItem, deleteMenuItem };
            MenuItems = items;
            Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel>(device.Sensors.Select(s => new TreeViewItemModel(s)));
        }

        else if (thing.GetType() == typeof(Sensor))
        {
            var sensor = (Sensor) thing;
            var space = sensor.Space.Name ?? string.Empty;
            var device = sensor.Device;
            ParentName = device == null ? "No Matching Device" : device.Name;
            Name = sensor.Id.ToString();
            Id = sensor.Id;
            ParentName = space;
            var updateMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "UpdateSensorInfo", Text = "Update Sensor Info" };
            var deleteMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "DeleteSensor", Text = "Delete Sensor" };
            var items = new ObservableCollection<MenuFlyoutItem> {updateMenuItem, deleteMenuItem};
            MenuItems = items;
            Children = null;
        }

    }
```

My TreeView in xaml looks like this:

```
<controls:TreeView x:Name="TreeViewList" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeSpaces}">
        <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                    <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
                </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <Button x:Name="TreeButton" Content="{Binding Name}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout common:BindableFlyout.ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                            <common:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </common:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:TreeView>
```

I can't seem to get any form of event handling to trigger on the MenuFlyoutItem to work.

Initially I tried `<MenuFlyoutItem Name={Binding Name} Text={Binding Text} view:EventHandlers.Attach="Click"/>` This works off a custom MVVM implementation to attach events to ViewModel handlers.  Behind the scenes, our attaching mechanism takes the Name of the object and associates with a Click so it would look like this in the View Model if the name were say SaveButton:  `public void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`.  Now, I've normally never had an issue with this, but I thought the problem might have stemmed from trying to use DataBinding for the MenuFlyoutItem's Name rather than the traditional `x:Name="blah blah"`; however, trying that did not work either.  I thought maybe this could be because it was a MenuFlyoutItem rather than a button per say, so I tried changing it to a `<Button/>` with all the respective stuff, and that didn't work either.  So, I went back to MenuFlyoutItem and tried to use the Command property instead.  i.e. `Command="{Binding MenuItemSelected}"`.  Then in my ViewModel I have the following:

```
public RelayCommand<object> MenuItemSelected { get; internal set; }
public TreeViewPageVM()
{
    MenuItemSelected = new RelayCommand<object>(TestAction);
}

private void TestAction(object sender)
{

}
```

That didn't work either...  So, as much as I want to use MVVM, I resulted to trying code behind by using the traditional `<MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="MenuItem" Text="{Binding Text} Click="MenuItem_Clicked"` and a corresponding `private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` handler.  Much to my surprise this didn't work either.  So, I'm not sure what's causing what seems like a suppression on my MenuFlyoutItem's ability to generate events, but some help on this would be appreciated.

Ideally whether it's a click event or command event, I'd like to handle it in my ViewModel, and I'd want the command or click event to be able to grab the `Content` on the button that generated the Flyout Menu (I'll need that during post processing of the event) as well as the `Text` from the MenuFlyoutItem that was clicked.

Just in case there needs to be any additional clarity:
I would have objects in the tree like so

```
----Object1
--------SubObject
```

and if I click on SubObject (which in this case is a Button that has a flyout attached) a flyout menu with options like: Add, Update, Delete show up.  When I click/tap on Add for example, I need my end event handler or command to be aware of SubObject (specifically it's Content because it's a button) and the MenuFlyoutItem that was clicked (specifically the Text property so I know whether I need to add, update, or delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and correct answer given above (i.e.adding the Command in the same code where you create the `MenuFlyoutItem`) leads to the fact that your code violates the MVVM pattern, because you create View's Controls in the ViewModel, so a better solution would be

1) implementing a ViewModel for the Flyout

```
public class DeviceViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        internal int treeNum;

        private DelegateCommand flyoutCommand;
        public ICommand FlyoutCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (flyoutCommand == null)
                {
                    flyoutCommand = new DelegateCommand((parameter) => FlyoutLogic(), (parameter) => CanFlyout());
                }
                return flyoutCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool CanFlyout()
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void FlyoutLogic()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("here we go " + Name + treeNum);
        }
    }
```

2) instantiating the ViewModel

```
                    var addDeviceMenuItem = new DeviceViewModel { Name = "AddDevice", treeNum = _itemId  };
                    var addSensorMenuItem = new DeviceViewModel { Name = "AddSensor", treeNum = _itemId  };
                    var addSpaceMenuItem = new DeviceViewModel { Name = "AddSpace", treeNum = _itemId  };
                    var updateMenuItem = new DeviceViewModel { Name = "UpdateSpaceInfo", treeNum = _itemId  };
                    var deleteMenuItem = new DeviceViewModel { Name = "DeleteSpace", treeNum = _itemId  };
                    var items = new ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> { addDeviceMenuItem, addSensorMenuItem, addSpaceMenuItem, updateMenuItem, deleteMenuItem };
                    tree.Add(
                        new TreeItemModel
                        {
                            Branch = b,
                            Depth = d,
                            Text = "Item " + _itemId++,
                            Children = BuildTree(d, b),
                            MenuItems = items
                });
```

with

```
ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> _menuItems;
public ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> MenuItems
{
    get { return _menuItems; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref _menuItems, value); }
}
```

3) and finally binding the XAML to the ViewModel

```
<controls:TreeView x:Name="TreeViewList" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
    <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
            </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
            <Button
                x:Name="TreeButton" Content="{Binding Text}" BorderThickness="3" Background="Transparent">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout common:BindableFlyout.ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                        <common:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding FlyoutCommand}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </common:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Command in the same code where you create the `MenuFlyoutItem`, so

```
 var addDeviceMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Name = "AddDevice", Text = "Add Device"
 };
 addDeviceMenuItem.Command = AddDeviceCommand;
```